# `mat-calendar` design not looking good when used in `mat-dialog`

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

In my angular 16 app i have used angular material. I want to display mat-calendar inside a modal popup dialog so i create a component and added `mat-calendar` inside it and load that component using `mat-dialog` but design of `mat-calendar` is not showing as expected. here i am attaching the screenshot of displaying calendar.

[image]

Here is code of my main component to open dialog

```
openDateTimePicker(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DateTimePickerComponent, {
    data: {},
  });

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data: any) => {
    if (data) {
    }
  });
}
```

And here is html code of DateTimePicker Component

```
<mat-calendar></mat-calendar>
```

I tried to find solution on angular material website and stackblitz but can't find similar examples.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by setting up width of dialog component

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DateTimePickerComponent, {
  data: {},
  width: '320px',
});
```